# Can I list multiple orderby's?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Good morning. 
I have implemented the ability to add replies. 
I have questions that I do not understand during implementation. 
Use orderby when using sorting. 
Can I use multiple orderbyes?
 Currently I only sort by time order. 
So, even if you reply, it goes up to the top of the page.
 You should sort by column, and the reply will appear under the word. 
How do I use multiple orderby?
[You should come to 1-1 under 1. And 1-2 should come under 1-1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHbi8.jpg)

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Notice(int? page)
    {
        var article = db.Articles.ToList().Where(c => c.Category == "공지사항").OrderByDescending(o => o.ModifyDate);
        var pageNumber = page ?? 1;                             
        var OnePageOfArticle = article.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);  
        ViewBag.OnePageOfList = OnePageOfArticle;
        ViewBag.TotalCount = db.Articles.Where(c => c.Category == "공지사항").Count();
        ViewBag.PageNumber = pageNumber;

        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<table class="footable table table-stripped toggle-arrow-tiny" data-page-size="3" id="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-toggle="true" data-sort-ignore="true" width="10%" class="text-center">번호</th>
                                <th width="55%" class="text-center">제목</th>
                                <th data-hide="phone,tablet" class="text-center" width="auto">글쓴이</th>
                                <th data-hide="phone" class="text-center" width="auto">작성일</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @{
                                int i = 0;
                                int idx = 0;
                            }
                            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.OnePageOfList)
                            {
                                idx = ViewBag.TotalCount - ((ViewBag.PageNumber - 1) * 10) - i;
                                String str = "공지사항";

                                if (@item.Category.Equals(str))
                                {
                                    var indent = 20 * item.Indent + "px";
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@idx.ToString()</td>
                                        <!--부모글-->
                                        @if (item.Indent == 0)
                                        {
                                            <td class="text-left"><a href="/Board/Detail?aidx=@item.ArticleIDX">@item.Title</a></td>
                                        }
                                        <!--답글-->
                                        @if (item.Indent != 0)
                                        {
                                            <td class="text-left" style="padding-left:@indent;"><a href="/Board/Detail?aidx=@item.ArticleIDX">└Re:@item.Title</a></td>
                                        }
                                        <td>
                                            @if (item.ModifyMemberID == item.Members.ID)
                                             {
                                                @item.Members.Name;
                                             }
                                        </td>
                                        <td>@Convert.ToDateTime(item.ModifyDate).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")</td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                                i++;
                            }
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="6"><ul class="pagination pull-right"></ul></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReplyCreate(Articles articles)
    {
        {
            if (TempData["aidx"] != null && TempData["family"] != null)
            {
                int aidx = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["aidx"]);
                var parent = db.Articles.Where(a => a.ArticleIDX == aidx).FirstOrDefault();

                var article = new Articles
                {
                    Family = parent.Family,
                    Parent = parent.ArticleIDX,
                    Depth = parent.Depth + 1,
                    Indent = parent.Indent + 1,
                    Title = articles.Title,
                    Contents = articles.Contents,
                    Category = parent.Category,
                    ModifyMemberID = User.Identity.Name,
                    ModifyDate = DateTime.Now
                };

                db.Articles.Add(article);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Notice");
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ThenBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. When I first used thenby, I thought I had a different way. I guess I should have made a mistake before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ThenBy` and also your code has some mistakes;

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Notice(int? page)
{
    var articles = db.Articles.Where(c => c.Category == "공지사항")
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.ModifyDate)
    .ThenBy(x => x.FieldName).ToList();
    var pageNumber = page ?? 1;              
    ViewBag.TotalCount = articles.Count;    
    var OnePageOfArticle = articles.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);  
    ViewBag.OnePageOfList = OnePageOfArticle;
    ViewBag.PageNumber = pageNumber;
    return View();
}
```

I have also some notes;

- Don't apply `Where` clause after pull the data from database. Apply the where condition directly in `IQueryable` form thus in the database.
- Be careful with name conveniences change the `article` to `articles`.
- You don't need to hit the database again for calculation list count. You already have the list and just calculate it as in-memory. (`Count`)
- There is no required to use `ViewBag` use `Model` instead. It is not proper way for MVC.

Comment: Thanks! You are very kind.

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

To add ordering by multiple columns try this.

```
var article = db.Articles.ToList().Where(c => c.Category == "공지사항").OrderByDescending(o => o.ModifyDate)
```

Try adding onto the `.OrderByDescending` a `.ThenBy(o => o.FieldName)`
or `.ThenByDescending(o => o.Fieldname)`